# Change Y-axis from exponential to integer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to convert a y-axis of my barplot from exponential to integer. However, the scaling (using scale_y_continuous) won't adjust my plot. 
u is just a simple dataframe, containing data about people who joined the query. The data frame contains the columns gender, id, zip code and age. Its a dataset with roughly 6500 rows.

I've tried using scale_y_continuous and discrete, it has not worked, though.

```
p<-ggplot(u, aes(x=gender, y=NROW(gender))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks=c(seq(0:6500)))+
  labs(x="Gender",y="Number of Votes")
p
```

Comment: The default scale in barplots is not exponential, so I do not understand your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your y values using nrow(). geom_bar has a "count" stat option for this type of plot:

```
p<-ggplot(u, aes(gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count", fill="steelblue")+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(x="Gender",y="Number of Votes")
p
```

Hopefully this also fixes your y-axis issue.